# How to read gnuplot's file input format to array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, readfile

#x  #y #z

```
1 1 1
1 2 4
1 3 9
1 4 16

2 1 1
2 2 4
2 3 9
2 4 16

3 1 1
3 2 4
3 3 9
3 4 16
...
```

How to read this file to array x, y, z?

where x from first column, y from first column, z from first column of file

I'd tried something already but i had some problem with blank line.

Comment: If you tried something, you should show your code. You should also explain little bit more what the numbers in the file mean, your explanation is strange.

Comment: @VladimirF Sir, just use read function to read file in ordinary way to three array variables but problem is happened because of blank lines. and for the meaning is this is just 3d data that have x, y, z data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is quite incomplete, but if I get your intention right, you can first read the line into a variable and test if it is empty or not

```
character(200) : line

i = 1
do
  read(unit, '(a)') line
  if (len_trim(line)>0) then
    read(line,*) x(i), y(i), z(i)
    i = i + 1
  end do
end do
```

Comment: thank you very much, this totally answer my question.